# Simple C Structs: Trouble storing a char * [] into a struct in C. Incompatible types

Tags: c, string, struct, printf

I am having trouble with a very simple C code in which I need to store an array of `char *` (Basically, an array of strings) in a struct.

I am getting the error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[41]’ from type ‘char **’
```

Here is the relevant code and explanation:

```
struct HistoryElement
{
  int NumberOfCommandGiven;
  char * command[MAXLINE/2+1];
};  

int main() {
  char *args[MAXLINE/2+1];
  setup(args); //This gets the command given by user and parses it into args.  This works properly.
  struct HistoryElement input;
  input.command = args; //How to accomplish this without error?
  printf("input.command:  %s",input.command); //Test
}
```

The error comes on the line where I am trying to set `input.command` to `args`.  Although they are both of type `char * []`, I get the incompatible types error.  I am sure this is somewhat simple to fix, but I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: this line: 'char * command[MAXLINE/2+1];' defines an array of POINTERS but does not allocate memory for each of those pointers to point to.

Comment: @user3629249: The idea is, apparently, that memory is managed by `setup` function, meaning that proper pointer values are returned from `setup` in `args` array. The pointers are supposedly valid, i.e. it is not our business to worry where they came from and where they point to.

Answer (score 3):

Naked arrays are not assignable. If you want to copy an array, use `memcpy` or write a manual cycle

```
#include <string.h>
...
memcpy(input.command, args, sizeof args);
```

Your "test" does not make sense though. Your `input.command` is not a string, it is an *array of string pointers*. You can't just do

```
printf("input.command:  %s", input.command);
```

on it.

Comment: True on the test, it was for previous code and i understand why that won't work.  I'll change it and report back.

Comment: This seems to be working, finally.  I am getting all of the arguments passed into the struct.  I will accept this as soon as i figure this out.